# how to validate with minor fixes only

Tags: asp.net, web-services, validation, c#-4.0

```
if (textbox1.Text.Length == 0)
        {               
            textbox1.Text = "*cannot be empty";
        }
        else
        {

            int checkNumber;
            if (int.TryParse(textbox1.Text, out checkNumber) == false)
            {
                textbox1.Text = "NUMBERS ONLY!";
                return;
            }
            else
            {

                if (textbox1.Text.Equals(0))
                {
                    textbox1.Text = "Invalid";
                }
                else
                {
                    textboxl.Text = "";
                }
            }
        }
```

This is my code and i have tested it and works. But I want to put a validation services, web service.

Is there a way to do it without having to change majority of the code. I just want to make it simple enough so that i can understand step by step.

my plan is to cut and paste this code into the web service with not too much of coding. This isnt for a real website by the way. just doing some simple testing so i dont mind if the security is weak.

It would be a great help if you could provide a step-by-step explanation.

Comment: Why don't you use client side validation?

Comment: what is a client side validation? sorry for my lack of knowledge, i am still learning the basics.

Comment: Using `JavaScript` and `JQuery` you can validate the conditions which are mentioned above. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yb52a4x0(v=vs.100).aspx, http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding, you should be doing something like below

```
public string ValidateInputString(string input)
{
   // Your Logic Here
   return responseString;
}
```

Call this method in the same place from UI where you have writeen this code.

Hope this Helps!!